# Reading a struct in binary with ifstream read()

Tags: c++

I'm trying to load a RTCW BSP file with different lumps defined as structs using ifstream's read() function, but I get the wrong values when I look at the variables in the debugger.

The first 2 structs are defined like this:

```
struct DirEntry
{
    int offset;
    int length;
};

struct Header
{
    char magic[4];
    int version;
    DirEntry direntries[17];
};
```

The code I use to read is this:

```
bool XWorldMap::Load(string filename, ID3D10Device* pd3d)
{
    ifstream mapfile;

    mapfile.open(filename.c_str(), ios::binary);

    if (!mapfile.is_open())
        return false;
    else
    {
        // read in header
        Header head;
        mapfile.read((char*)(&head), sizeof(head));
    }

    return true;
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
Header head;
mapfile.read((char*)(&head.magic), sizeof(head.magic));
mapfile.read((char*)(&head.version), sizeof(head.version));
```

Still don't get the right values.

I'm pretty sure it has to do with the struct padding in the file but I don't know how to set it correctly...

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try just creating a `Header`, write it to a file, read it into a new `Header` and then inspect if it is the same or not.  A [mcve] like that should help you find where the problem is.

Comment: Can you add to your question a hexadecimal dump of the initial portion of the file that you are trying to load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually if you want to read struct that way you need to ensure that there is no padding in your structs.

try something like this to ensure that compiler doesn't insert extra padding bytes around your char variable:

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct DirEntry
{
    int offset;
    int length;
};

struct Header
{
    char magic[4];
    int version;
    DirEntry direntries[17];
};
#pragma pack()
```

However, since you have char[4], I don't thing that pragma pack(1) would change binary layout of your struct. Can you provide more details about what's not expected with the way you read your data?

Comment: What can't there be padding?  `write` and `read` should write and read all the bytes in the class including the padding ones as you read and write `sizeof(Header)` bytes.

Comment: @Hermetix if that resolves, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: @NathanOliver what if the input file was generated elsewhere?

Comment: @Pavel Good point.  In that case you need to do something (like this) to makes the structs lay out in memory the same.

Comment: @Pavel why would the compiler add padding to a struct definition? Is this like this for all compilers? I'm using VC++ 2017 btw.

Comment: @Hermetix I'm a bit surprised that compiler added padding in your case, but in general compiler is free to do that for optimization purposes. `#pragma pack` is a non-standard extension that tells compiler not to do that.